# How to get specific address from file upload dialog python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to select a file using file upload dialog i am using this code

```
def buttonClick():
            self.label = Label(master,text=askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Android Application Files", ".apk"), ("All files", "*.*"))))
            self.label.grid()
            self.upButton.destroy()
```

[image]
I get the complete address of file but i only want the name and extension in selection as highlighted in this picture

Guide me ,anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename). For example, if `path = /a/b/c.apk`, then `os.path.basename(path)` returns `c.apk`

Comment: you mean this way? 
  self.label = Label(master,text=askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Android Application Files", ".apk"), ("All files", "*.*"))))
            os.path.basename(self.label)

Comment: I'll leave this to you, but note that `os.path.basename(self.label)` won't do anything. Instead you need `self.label = os.path.basename(self.label)`

Comment: i dont understand it. can you help me with the code? you can see my above code it working perfectly fine. i just want to get the file name and extension so tell me how do i do it with existing code above?

Comment: If `self.label` is your path, then all you need to do is `self.label = os.path.basename(self.label)` to extract the filename and extension from the path.

Comment: its giving me this error: Exception in Tkinter callback

Comment: thanks alot its done. i changed a little logic. i was storing file path in a label. i now have stored it in a variable and have used os.path.basename and yes it works !

Answer (score -1):

For this question, you can do like this:

```
str = r"E:/FYP/FYPPP/AMARP/try.apk"
result = str.split(r"/")[-1]
```

Comment: But i am geting the file from file uplaod dialog how do i split it ? i am not hard coding the file path.